# How to approach making "alignment guides" for snapping? Similar to image softwares like photoshop/figma

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

We're creating an app with unity where the user can position objects in the 3D space, along two axes (Z, X, so no height).

And there's a case where the object needs to align against other objects or the "outer canvas".

This is pretty similar to how Figma or Photoshop handles its "smart guides"/"alignment guides", here's an example on Figma, look at the "red lines":
[image: example of positioning objects with alignment guides on figma]

Video version of this gif: https://imgur.com/WmaYuAr.mp4

But we're confused about how to approach/implement it. Not sure exactly how to do it.  We tried implementing it using raycasts but with no success.

Where can I find resources to learn how to implement something similar to this? How could we approach it?